# Los datos en local storage se pierden al refrescar la pagina

Tags: javascript

```js
const d = document;

function AddElements() {
    
    const send = d.getElementById("send");
    send.addEventListener("click", e => {
        const $uno = d.getElementById("uno").value;
        const $dos = d.getElementById("dos").value;
        const $cinco = d.getElementById("cinco").value;
        const $diez = d.getElementById("diez").value;
        const $veinte = d.getElementById("veinte").value;
        const $cincuenta = d.getElementById("cincuenta").value;
        const $cien = d.getElementById("cien").value;
        const $docientos = d.getElementById("docientos").value;
        const $quinientos = d.getElementById("quinientos").value;
        const $morralla = d.getElementById("morralla").value;
        const $dolares = d.getElementById("dolares").value;
       

         let sum = parseInt($uno) + parseInt($dos) + parseInt($cinco) + parseInt($diez) + parseInt($veinte) + parseInt($cincuenta) + parseInt($cien) + parseInt($docientos) + parseInt($quinientos) + parseInt($morralla) + parseInt($dolares);
        
         addToModal(sum)
       
    })
   
  
}
  
const addToModal =function(sum){
    const $modal = d.getElementById("modal");
    $modal.innerHTML=sum;
    ModalToLocal(sum)
}



const ModalToLocal=function(sum){
   let array=[sum]
   localStorage.setItem("venta-dia",JSON.stringify(array))
   
}



const  getLocalStorage = function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("venta-dia")){
        let sale = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("venta-dia"));
         console.log(sale)
    }else{
        return "No hay entradas para la localSTORAGE "
    }
  
    
    
}


AddElements()
ModalToLocal()
getLocalStorage()
```

Estoy realizando un  ejercicio para guardar en local storage pero no logro hacer que el valor se mantenga porque al refrescar la pagina se pierden los datos.

Mí código es el siguiente :

```js
const ModalToLocal=function(sum){
   let array=[sum]
   localStorage.setItem("venta-dia",JSON.stringify(array))
   
}



const  getLocalStorage = function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("venta-dia")){
        let sale = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("venta-dia"));
         console.log(sale)
    }else{
        return "No hay entradas para la localSTORAGE "
    }
  
    
    
}
```

El código HTML lo omito pensando en que ya saben que todo lo voy cachando en el javascript , lo que estoy haciendo es  un contador de monedas, son 11 inputs que reciben valores con los cuales se hace una suma  y el valor lo mostramos en una ventanita modal,pero ahora quiero que el mismo valor se guarde en el localstorage.

Comment: 100% seguro de que no hay otra cosa iniciando el storage desde 0?

Comment: pues solo veo la variable  del storage y su valor ... como comenté logro hacer que inserte y tambien puedo recuperarlo pero lo que no puedo es que el valor permanesca aun después de refrescar la página

Comment: Si tiras en la consola del navegador:  `localStorage`, luego de refrescar la pagina, que te mustra ?

Comment: Pregunto por que estoy probando este mismo codigo en la pestaña esta, y funciona ok.

Comment: Recibo desde unas input valores  ese valor lo recojo y lo meto en la local storage , a la primera recarga  el marca null porque no hay nada, pero ya enviando  se rellena el valor  y cuando refresco vuelve a null y ese es mi problema bueno mas bien  es la suma de varias input

Comment: No ya ningun otro script que pueda estar reiniciando el storge? al estilo: `localStorage.clear();`

Comment: no  de hecho mi codigo js es el que ya probaste , las demas funciones no tienen nada que ver con la storage, ati si te guarda  refrescando?

Comment: Si. Me guarda perfecto. Estas trabajando con js plano, o con react, vuejs, etc?

Comment: si es js puro, que raro la verdad  y la verdad es que me estoy dando cuenta que mi funcion get item  me da null en la consola pero set item si estáa guardando

Comment: Salvo que sea algo del navegador, puedes probar tirar tu codigo en otra pestaña nueva de cualquier otra web, para ver si hace lo mismo?

Comment: 'no deefinitivamente  no se que sea  lo probé en otro navegdor y  me dio lo mism0  no  hay  manera que veas todo el codigo?

Comment: Pero probaste en una pestaña de otra web cualquier?, Por ej en esta misma pestaña? Puedes compartir todo el codigo por aqui o es mucho?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136591/discussion-between-julian-ontiveros-ramirez-and-karl-kno).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando el código que has adjuntado veo que al final ejecutas estas tres funciones y creo que ahí puede estar el problema.

```
AddElements()
ModalToLocal()
getLocalStorage()
```

A continuación te digo el por qué:

`ModalToLocal` requiere una variable como parámetro, al no recibirla al ser ejecutada en esta parte final del script, se ejecuta pero el parámetro `sum` será `undefined` y por tanto al intentar guardar este valor en el localStorage lo guardará como `null`.

Para evitar esto no debes ejecutar esta función (`ModalToLocal`) en este punto del script, ya que se ejecutará al cargar la ventana, destruyendo lo que hubiera guardado previamente.

Dado que `AddElements` ya ejecuta internamente a `ModalToLocal` simplemente no ejecutes esta última en esta posición y debería dejar de dar problema.

Comment: Efectivamente esa es la solución  llamaba a la función dos veces , lo resolvi  quitando la llamada a la función abajo.  Marcaré con punto arriba y doy por cerrado el tema